# How to only minus 1 point from the score if user presses the back button?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Below is the back button, but the user should lose 1 point only once from pressing the button any other time he presses the button it won't deduct another point?

```
- (IBAction)btnback:(id)sender {
NSString *backspace = _textbox.text;
int lengthofstring = backspace.length;
if(lengthofstring > 0)
backspace = [backspace substringToIndex:lengthofstring -1];
_textbox.text = backspace;
if (lengthofstring < 2)
    [_textXclear setHidden:YES];

score = score -1;
```

and it should only deduct 1 point after the first letter is typed!

How is this done right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bool.
Delcare a `BOOL` ivar like so `BOOL minusPoint`.

In your `viewDidLoad` initialize it: `minusPoint = YES`.

Then in your `IBAction` do:

```
if(minusPoint) {
    //Minus a point
    minusPoint = NO;
}
```

then set `minusPoint` to yes whenever you want to subtract a point again.

Comment: if(minusPoint) { score = score -1;
        
        minusPoint = NO; like this right?

Comment: @user3449971 Yes you can also just do score -= 1;